# How to make sure the color of the word ISNT the color the word says

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've been working on a Stroop test in code for a while now and I have almost finished it completely, aside from one single thing. For the final 2 of the 6 tests, the colored word needs to show a different color than the word (eg if the word is "Green" the color can't be green).

I've tried changing the lists that I use and literally just tried writing color != text because I was hoping that would work, but it didn't. Every time I try modifying the lists or playing with them it just gets worse and I don't understand exactly how it works.

```
if numbertest == 6:
  tina.color('black');style = ('Arial', 20, 'bold');tina.write('Instructions in console below', font=style, align='center')
  print ('In 10 seconds you will be shown a colored word on the screen. Type the first letter of the COLOR, then hit enter. Then hit enter a second time, and the next word will be shown.')
  time.sleep(10)
  tina.clear()
  while nooftrials < 10:
    index = random.randint(0, len(colors) -1)
    color = colors[index]
    text = random.choice(texts)
    tina.color(color);style = ('Arial', 20, 'bold');tina.write(text, font=style, align='center')
    t0 = time.time()
    answer = str(raw_input("Letter of color: "))
    nooftrials += 1
```

The expected result is that the `tina.write(text...)` will write a word and the `tina.color(color)` will be a different color than the text, eg if the text is "Blue" the color of the word isn't blue. However, at the moment it is random and sometimes congruent sets come up, even though this part is meant to be different words and color.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a random color, then make sure to choose a random word as long as it is not the same as the chosen color (or the other way around):

```
color = random.choice(colors)
text = color
while text == color:
    text = random.choice(texts)
```

In action:

```
import random

colors = list(range(2))
texts = list(range(2))

color = random.choice(colors)
text = color
while text == color:
    print(f'color is {color}, text is {text}')
    text = random.choice(texts)

print(f'finally, color is {color}. text is {text}')
```

Sample output:

```
color is 1, text is 1
finally, color is 1. text is 0
```

This may be sub-optimal.

Another option is to pick a color then remove it from `texts` and only then pick a random word. This will guarantee `color` and `text` to be different. This will work as long as the words in `texts` are unique because `list.remove` only removes the first occurrence.

```
import random

colors = list(range(5))
texts = list(range(5))

color = random.choice(colors)
texts.remove(color)
text = random.choice(texts)

print(f'finally, color is {color}. text is {text}')
```

Sample output

```
finally, color is 4. text is 2
```